# How to record GA click events on fontello icons?

Tags: google-analytics, fontello

I am using fontello to display share icons as below. I am trying to add Google Analytics such that if anyone clicks it is recorded. Currently, all I get is empty values. My GA code is below. How to fix it so that it records whether click is done on facebook, twitter or instagram icon?

```
    /* Tracks all a href links */
    $('a').click(function(e){
        ga('send','event','Link (Shares)', 'Click (Shares)',$(this).text().trim());
    }) 
/* html of the share code is below*/
<div class="swf-share-icons">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/google" class="share-icon" title="Follow us on facebook"><i class="icon-facebook-squared"></i></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/google" class="share-icon" title="Follow us on Twitter"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="https://instagram.com/google" class="share-icon" title="Follow us on Twitter"><i class="icon-instagramm"></i></a
</div>
```

Comment: That code looks correct to me. Have you check the JavaScript console for errors? Have you inspected the network tab to see if anything is actually being when you click on a link?